# In what state is the Database after a failed Entity Framework migration?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We're considering switching to Entity Framework code-first with migrations and following scenario came up:

We have 3 pending migrations:

Migration 1 works

Migration 2 fails

Migration 3 works

After I run migrations, what state is the database in? Does it roll back everything, does it do migration 1 and rolls it back when 2 fails? Is migration 2 rolled back and 1 and 3 complete regularly?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the migrator will abort when it hits a migration that it can't apply, but does not rollback any prior migrations. In your example, the database would be in a state with only migration 1 applied and you should get a message that migration 2 contains errors.

To force a manual rollback, use the `Update-Database` command with the `-TargetMigration <Full Migration Name>` option. You must define the Down() method in your migrations for this to work properly.

A transaction is created for each individual migration, and commited at the end of each migration, i.e. each migration is applied in full or not at all.

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, so I marked it. An all-or-nothing approach would be much better for automated deployment though.